# Apple watch complication log on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, watchkit

When I run my  WatchKit Complication Apple Watch app, Xcode console log this: "Extension received request to wake up for complication support".

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the WatchExtension code wakes up when your complication update cycle starts.  This occurs prior to (normally) a call to the complication functions of requestedUpdateDidBegin() or getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication:().